# Gitignore for collaborative Java programming with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, collaboration, gitignore

Which files can be ignored when programming in Java with Eclipse in a team? We were arguing in our team that the `.classpath` and `.project` file should or shouldn't be included in the repository.

I don't really want to include those, but don't really have any real arguments, why I wouldn't want to include them. I just have the feeling that they don't belong in the repository.

Is the `.classpath` and .project` file needed to have consistency in our project, if everyone is working with Eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

We do not put any IDE-specific files under version control, and I would avise against it. Many of them may (an thus often will) contain absoulte paths, inconsistent user-defined libraries etc. Those in turn will break builds on a regular basis, make build-out-of-the-box impossible, make CI difficult and are generally redundant.

We are using maven, - the `pom.xml` is sufficient to reconstruct the project acrioss IDE and OS boundaries. I am sure, same results can be achieved with ant too.

Comment: You could also make use of what's been provided to help keep those files portable.  The .project file itself should be fine.  If the user libraries are inconsistently defined, *fix* them on the developer machines where they're not doing it right.

Answer (score 0):

Working with eclipse, the `.project` and `.classpath` are expected to be saved in source control along with the source.  That's the way it's designed.  As [@nitind](https://stackoverflow.com/users/27905/nitind) mentioned, you don't include any absolute paths to jars in the classpath, taking advantage of variables and user libraries for 3rd party libraries that can be installed in different locations.

But it's not required.  The other option is to have developers create their own workspace and their own project and then created linked resources to the source on the filesystem once pulled from the SCM.